# Filter graphql data from frontend using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I have the following React page in Gatsby repo which runs a graphql page query to Netlify CMS to fetch the data :

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Layout from '../../components/Layout';
import Dropdown from '../../components/Dropdown';
import CardBlock from '../../components/creditcards/CardBlock';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';

const CCListing = (response) => {
    console.log("Credit Cards Listings")
    console.log(response);
    const {creditCards} = response.data;
    return (
        <CCListingContainer>
            <Layout>
                <div className="container">
                    <h1 className="section-title">Recommended cards for you</h1>
                    <h4 className="section-subtitle">Based on your answers, we’ve provided the top matches for you to compare below. Review and select the one that best matches your needs.</h4>
                    <div className="filters-container">
                        <Dropdown default="Travel" />
                        <Dropdown default="No Annul Fee" />
                        <Dropdown default="Welcome Bonus" />
                        <Dropdown default="Low to High" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="cards-container">
                        {creditCards.edges.map(item => (
                            <CardBlock cardData={item}  />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Layout>
        </CCListingContainer>
    )
}

const CCListingContainer = styled.div`
    .filters-container {
        margin-top: 50px;
        display: flex;
    }
    .cards-container {
        margin-top: 2rem;
    }
`

export const pageQuery = graphql`
query CreditCardListing {
    creditCards:allMarkdownRemark(filter: {frontmatter:{ templateKey: { eq: "credit-card-post" } }}) {
      edges {
        node {
          frontmatter {
            title
            cardImage {
              childImageSharp {
                fixed(width: 299, height: 189) {
                    ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
                }
              }
            }
            fee
            purchaseInterest
            cashAdvanceInterest
            href
            summaryDescription
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

export default CCListing;
```

On this page, I have these dropdowns at the top for filtering data coming from query :

[image]

How can I filter data based on dropdown selections ? Not sure how to introduce variables or react hooks in graphql query to make it dynamic.

Comment: You won't be able to pass variables in your GraphQL query rather than the context.

Comment: @FerranBuireu can you help me with the approach ? How can I move ahead with this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a broad question and without having a CodeSandbox or something similar it's difficult to figure out how the code will behave. However, what you need to do, is to add the GraphQL query result to the state and then play with the state:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Layout from '../../components/Layout';
import Dropdown from '../../components/Dropdown';
import CardBlock from '../../components/creditcards/CardBlock';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';

const CCListing = (response) => {
    console.log("Credit Cards Listings")
    console.log(response);
    const {creditCards} = response.data;

   const [yourData, setYourData]= useState({}); // initially set to empty to avoid re-hydration issues or asynchronous execution issues if the data is empty   

    useEffect(() => {
        setYourData(creditCards)
    },[])
   
   yourHandleFunction= ()=>{
     // your stuff here. You may need to clone your state object and manipulate the copy, depending on your use-case.
   }

    return (
        <CCListingContainer>
            <Layout>
                <div className="container">
                    <h1 className="section-title">Recommended cards for you</h1>
                    <h4 className="section-subtitle">Based on your answers, we’ve provided the top matches for you to compare below. Review and select the one that best matches your needs.</h4>
                    <div className="filters-container">
                        <Dropdown onClick={yourHandleFunction} default="Travel" />
                        <Dropdown onClick={yourHandleFunction} default="No Annul Fee" />
                        <Dropdown onClick={yourHandleFunction} default="Welcome Bonus" />
                        <Dropdown onClick={yourHandleFunction} default="Low to High" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="cards-container">
                        {creditCards.edges.map(item => (
                            <CardBlock cardData={item}  />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Layout>
        </CCListingContainer>
    )
}

const CCListingContainer = styled.div`
    .filters-container {
        margin-top: 50px;
        display: flex;
    }
    .cards-container {
        margin-top: 2rem;
    }
`

export const pageQuery = graphql`
query CreditCardListing {
    creditCards:allMarkdownRemark(filter: {frontmatter:{ templateKey: { eq: "credit-card-post" } }}) {
      edges {
        node {
          frontmatter {
            title
            cardImage {
              childImageSharp {
                fixed(width: 299, height: 189) {
                    ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
                }
              }
            }
            fee
            purchaseInterest
            cashAdvanceInterest
            href
            summaryDescription
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

export default CCListing;
```

It's quite self-explanatory. You need to set your state with `useState` (initially as empty to prevent any type of asynchronous execution that may break the code) and, once the DOM tree is loaded (`useEffect` with empty deps, `[]`), your hook will fill your state with your GraphQL data with  `setYourData(creditCards)`.

The next step is to attach an `onClick` function event on your dropdowns and do your stuff there. Keep in mind that, depending on your needs and your use-case, you may need to copy the state object to avoid issues with your data. Something like this should work:

```
const clonedData = [...yourData]; // use {} if it's an object
```

Comment: Yes actually this was the last option for me. I was hoping there was some way I can query filtered data through graphql only. Anyways thanks

Comment: Please consider accepting/upvoting the answer if the issue has been solved